# OSX Statusbar: Styled menu item in Xcode/Qt

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, statusbar

what is this type of status bar icon called (the big one with the black background)?

[image: Statusbar large Icon]

I'm able to create a simple menu bar icons in xcode with no problem but I don't know how the create such a big styled app icon.
I don't even know how it is called so that i could search for it...

And is it possible to create such an icon in qt (for a OSX application)?

Thanks,
FMK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These icons are called [NSStatusItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/). There are a lot deprecated methods on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) and there is a new way to create those using NSStatusBarButton. 
You can find more information in this post: [How to develop status bar app in OS X Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807246/how-to-develop-status-bar-app-in-os-x-yosemite)